# an example of oneToMany relationship forms in play framework 2 (Java)

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have following two models; Country and State

```
class Country extends Model {
//country has many states
}

class State extends Model{
//state belongs to country
}
```

In my scenario, a country has many states and I want users to create and add as many states as they want.

I am new to play framework and looking for a good example of inherited form so that a user can dynamically add multiple state sub-forms and save/edit them.

I would really appreciate a simple example form for above case.

Answer (score 0):

Using a discriminator value, this will do it. I have not tired inheritance with Ebean yet, and I don't see why the discriminator would be required (as i use below, but I was getting errors without it) when using TablePerClass strategy.  OpenJPA has some examples of others. Ebean follows most of JPA, so it may not work exactly as JPA, you will have to try and see.

```
package models.test;

import play.db.ebean.Model;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Created by aakture on 3/12/14.
 */
@Entity
@Inheritance (strategy= InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@DiscriminatorValue("S")
public class State extends Model {
    @Id
    protected Long id;

    protected String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

package models.test;

import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

/**
 * Created by aakture on 3/12/14.
 */
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("MS")
public class MyState extends State {
    String addedProperty;

    public String getAddedProperty() {
        return addedProperty;
    }

    public void setAddedProperty(String addedProperty) {
        this.addedProperty = addedProperty;
    }
}

package models.test;

import play.db.ebean.Model;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by aakture on 3/12/14.
 */
@Entity
public class Country extends Model {
    @Id
    Long id;

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<State> states;

    public List<State> getStates() {
        return states;
    }

    public void setStates(List<State> states) {
        this.states = states;
    }
    public static Model.Finder<Long, Country> find = new Model.Finder<Long, Country>(
            Long.class, Country.class);
}
```

and a test:

```
@Test
public void testCountryState() {
    Country country = new Country();
    country.setName("Canada");
    List<State> states = new ArrayList<State>();
    State state = new State();
    state.setName("This is a State");
    states.add(state);
    MyState mystate = new MyState();
    mystate.setName("This is a MyState");
    mystate.setAddedProperty("an added property");
    states.add(mystate);
    country.setStates(states);
    country.save();

    country = Country.find.where().eq("name", "Canada").findUnique();

}
```

Comment: I asked about how to use build forms for inheritance.

Comment: Ok, I didn't try it with a form, but the inheritance strategy would be the same. I will try it when I get a chance, but http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaForms says you just create the form with Form<State> userForm = form(State.class); and then bind it, so I would think you could bind any subclass of State. Is that what you're trying to do?